# Django honeypot problems with url

Tags: django, honeypot

I'm trying to use the honeypot admin for my 3.2 Django projet
On docs they said we need to use a URL like this:

```py
urlpatterns = patterns(''
    ...
    url(r'^admin/', include('admin_honeypot.urls', namespace='admin_honeypot')),
    url(r'^secret/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    ...
)
```

But it seems `url` is old now and we had to use `re_path`.
I tried to use, re_path,URL, and path but still, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 975, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/mehdi/Desktop/mynewproject/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mehdi/Desktop/mynewproject/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/home/mehdi/Desktop/mynewproject/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/home/mehdi/Desktop/mynewproject/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 394, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/home/mehdi/Desktop/mynewproject/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mehdi/Desktop/mynewproject/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/mehdi/Desktop/mynewproject/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 116, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/home/mehdi/Desktop/mynewproject/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 269, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/mehdi/Desktop/mynewproject/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/admin_honeypot/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
ImportError: cannot import name 'ugettext_lazy' from 'django.utils.translation' (/home/mehdi/Desktop/mynewproject/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py)
```

https://django-admin-honeypot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual/usage.html

Comment: Your `django_honeypot` (version) is simply incompatible with the Django version, since `ugettext_lazy` was removed.

Comment: then what I have to do?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem
I'm currently using the last version of honeypot. Which version is compatible with Django 3.2?

Comment: well then it seems `django_honeypot` has not been updated to work with the last Django versions.